# How to preprocess two images to improve SIFT matching?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matching, sift

I want to match SIFT between several images taken from different devices posed in different positions in order to estimate crowds (i.e. devices that are looking at the same subject/scene)... But using the common SIFT matching (in grayscale->single representation) it fails!.. I think this occur due to the different devices representation.
So my questiona are: does exist some preprocessing method to run on these images before SIFT?... has any sense applying sift in each of the three channels (RGB or others.. like Lab which should be device independent) ?
Furthermore, if i used Lab due its device independence... how can i cast the image into "single" ? the VL feat library requires that images has to be of the type single for the SIFT detection but my lab representation uses double values in ranges [0 100] for L and [-110 110] for a and b.

Comment: To convert into single, just do `single(img)`. Remember SIFT is not perfect, it has many false matches. Without looking at the image, its difficult to make any comment.

Comment: hi, using single(img) do i will not have any cut/floor/ceil of values? (such as negative values of a and b channels..)... the images are not trivial for SIFT, but colors are different.. for example i have a person in the center (trivial for sift due it is not rigid) and several rigid objects such as a window curtain, a table, objects on the table (which should be easy for sift matching)

Comment: It will just change the precision of values which should not matter in this application.

Comment: I would try applying histogram equalization to both images, before extracting SIFT descriptors.